# neo4j database size is very large

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I have a graph with the following information:

50,000 Nodes

3,500,000 Relations

All nodes have label "music" with the following properties:

Name: String (max 6 chars)

ID: Integer

Played: Boolean

and all Relationships are "T1" with no properties.

why database size is too large and 2.5 GiB while in "neo4j hardware sizing calculator" tells me "Estimated size on disk" is less than 100 MB!

why Relationships add too much to Database size? Every 1,000,000 Relationships add 1 GB to my database size!

It should be noted that I have not deleted any nodes or relationships.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you paste the Store Sizes output of executing `:sysinfo` in the browser?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Sure. Of course I have changed some data in database since the question, but still it is too big. Here is sysinfo:
Store Sizes:
Array Store 8.00 KiB
Logical Log 168.67 MiB
Node Store 1.58 MiB
Property Store 2.38 MiB
Relationship Store 203.90 MiB
String Store 8.00 KiB
Total Store Size 4.04 GiB
ID Allocation:
Node ID 110062
Property ID 60842
Relationship ID 6288446
Relationship Type ID 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of transaction log files. 
Transaction files in `neo4j/databases` folder are used to backup transactions and be restored in case of losing data. 
Maximum size of transaction files can be restricted in config file. 
It's recommended to stop neo4j before deleting log files.